# Delete all leaves in a tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

Hey guys i have a problem. I would like to delete all leaves of a tree.
My init of a tree is `data NBaum a = NBlatt a | NKnoten a [NBaum a]`. I have no idea how i can do this and which is the command that the Nblatt is empty. Maybe u guys can help me.

My function should take a NBaum as an input and the output is a NBaum too.`entferneBlaetter :: NBaum a -> NBaum a`

I tried already  this code but it's wrong:

```
entferneBlaetter (NBlatt _) = NBlatt "test"
entferneBlaetter (NKnoten a b) = NKnoten a (entferneBlaetter_help b)
```

Comment: What should `entferneBlaetter (NBlatt 1)` evaluate to?

Comment: What if you give the method an `NBlatt` as intial value? You cannot remove a leaf from a leaf...

Comment: Furthermore the code is not *per se* wrong as a start, It only depends on what you will do with `entferneBlaetter_help`.

Comment: how many  `a` values can your tree hold? Can it hold  one `a` value? (In how many ways?) Is a leaf a tree? (it is, according to the data definition). If you remove the leaf from a 1-element leaf tree, shouldn't the result hold zero `a` values? Can your tree hold zero `a` values? Is there a difference between `Nblatt 7` and `NKnoten 7 []`? Do you really need `Nblatt a` at all?

Comment: Would be good to define specifically what you mean by "leaf", as `NBlatt "test"` and `NKoten "test" []` both don't "recurse" and hold other nodes. Are they both to be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint.

When dealing with `NKnoten a b`, we want to:

- scan all the trees in the `b` list:

  - if we find a leaf tree, we remove it from the list
  - if we find a node tree, we recursively remove the leaves from the subtrees of that node, and keep the result in the list.

A basic approach could be to write your `entferneBlaetter_help` recursively.

By the way, I think this exercise would best be realized using `entferneBlaetter :: NBaum a -> Maybe (NBaum a)`.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, apologies if you’ve gotten this far already:

Since, in Haskell, your trees are immutable, removing something from one means constructing a new tree without it.  Hence the type `entferneBlaetter :: NBaum a -> NBaum a`.

All your leaves appear to be either `NBlatt a` nodes, or possibly `NKnoten a []` nodes if that’s allowed.  But observe that, once you descend to a `NKnoten` node, it’s too late; there’s nothing you can return to construct a tree without one.

But you always scan the parent branch first, and the parent of a leaf node is always a `NKnoten`.  So you might try to `filter` the list of daughter nodes.  This might, however, leave you with a bare branch, `NKnoten a []`.  So, if you’re allowed to change the type signature of entferneBlaetter, you could pass a `Maybe NBaum` up to the caller, and it could then check whether all the daughter nodes evaluated to `Nothing`, then pass back either the pruned branch or replace `NKnoten a []` with `NBlatt a`.

As a bonus, if your tree consists of a single leaf node, you would then be able to prune it to `Nothing`.  But if your interface is fixed, you can still define a helper function `entferneBlaetter' :: NBaum -> Maybe NBaum`.

Alternatively, you could make a second transformation pass that replaces all instances of `NKnoten a []` with `NBlatt a`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't 100% specified in terms of what constitutes leaves and what should happen when the tree only has a single node. However, if we come up with a definition of "leaf" ...

```
isLeaf :: NBaum a -> Bool
isLeaf (NBlatt _)     = True
isLeaf (NKnoten _ []) = True
isLeaf _              = False
```

... we can give a recursive solution, recursing for each node in the list that is not a leaf, or removing it if it is.

```
entferneBlaetter :: NBaum a -> NBaum a
entferneBlaetter (NKnoten s xs) = NKnoten s [entferneBlaetter x | x <- xs, not $ isLeaf x]
entferneBlaetter x              = x
```